# How do I keep my paper perfectly flat on flatbed scanner?

Tags: scanning, scanner

I am scanning a photobook, I have unbinded the book and scanning the pages one by one to my Epson Perfection v600. The problem I ran into is that the pages couldn't lay completely flat on the bed, the pressure from the cover was not strong enough. It was okay for individual pages as they are not that noticeable but it became a problem when I have pages that needs to be stitch together in Photoshop, I have a hard time aligning them.

I tried putting credit card size cards on top of the paper but they were just way too small to cover the entire page. What other methods can I do?

Comment: You could cut a big mousepad to the desired size. That should lay flat and have enough weight to flatten a single sheet.

Comment: What? "credit card size cards?" What happens if you close the cover and then lay a couple of Big *** books on top?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't want to break my scanner

Comment: @KaiMattern Hi, I tested on my SteelSeries size medium mouse pad which weighted 4.8 ounces but it was not heavy enough to flatten the binding side (curls up) of the paper.

Comment: @KaiMattern [Please put your answers in the answer section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a book or two that are bigger than the sheet of paper. You won't be able to close the lid, but that shouldn't be an issue - the scanner will still scan. Obviously the glass is fragile to a point - you don't want to put 50 lb of stuff on it - but it should be plenty strong to handle a book or two. The important bit is making sure that at least the first book is larger than the sheet of paper, so it holds down the entire sheet.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I put a 1.4lb book on it and the curl up side of the paper was flattened nicely. Another thing that surprises me was that the book was 17mm in thickness but the scanner was able to scan it with a big gap on the closed lid. I compared the scans with and without the book and there was literally no difference in color and brightness, they look exactly the same.

Answer (score -3):

Use a single sheet of paper to scan from  and lower the lid all the way.